# Error "undfined is not a function (evaluating '_this2.props.handlepopupDismissed()')"

Tags: reactjs, react-native

Consider:

```
componentDidMount() {
  FingerprintScanner
    .authenticate({
    onAttempt: this.handleAuthenticationAttempted
  })
    .then(() => {
    this.props.handlePopupDismissed();
    Alert.alert('Fingerprint Authentication', 'Authenticated successfully');
  })
    .catch((error) => {
    this.setState({
      errorMessage: error.message
    });
    this.description.shake();
  });
}
```

In the above code, the below mentioned error shows when executing on the real device. How can I fix it?

> **undfined is not a function (evaluating '_this2.props.handlepopupDismissed()')**

Comment: seems like the prop `handlePopupDismissed` was not passed to the component

Comment: Please add relevant code of handlePopupDismissed

Comment: it would be helpful if you post code of `handlePopupDismissed` but based on error either you can bind the `handlePopupDismissed` function in constructor or change `handlePopupDismissed ` to arrow function like `handlePopupDismissed = (params) => {}`

Comment: The misspelling *"undfined"* (of *[undefined](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/undefined#Adjective)*) might be a clue. Was *"undfined"* actually in the error message?